# Is codekicker using the software behind StackOverflow or did they program a clone?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, clone

In germany a Stackoverflow-like site was created, that is very, very similar to Stackoverflow in the mechanics of reputation and badges etc. That is so similar, that I think they could use the same software. Did you sell it to them? Or are they using a very similar clone-software? The Community I have in mind is [Codekicker](http://codekicker.de/).

Comment: When in doubt, check this list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/so-clones/

Comment: Nein.

Comment: @Jarrod: Improving your German ;)

Comment: My German's a little better than I thought.  I can actually follow some of those questions.  I guess it helps that a lot of the keywords/technologies are still listed in English.

Comment: Also: I've seen Russian, Chinese, and now German clones.  What's next?   Japanese? Indian?

Comment: Anne McCaffrey fan, I take it?

Comment: At least I like some of the books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a shame that they don't even mention where they have the idea from. Wouldn't make the site any worse to admit that the idea comes from Stack Overflow—and as it seems, they copied basically everything (except that you only need 250 rep for editing other people's answers). The only results for

> stack overflow site:codekicker.de

in Google (this includes the blog) is a something about a "real" stack overflow, and [this question](http://codekicker.de/fragen/Wieso-klont-man-stumpf-stackoverflow.com/155) from yesterday. Here's my translation for the non-Germans:

> **Why would you clone stackoverflow.com so blatantly?**
>
> — without mentioning the one who came up with your "features" anywhere with a "thank you"...
>
> Take a look at cnprog.com, I hope you're going to share their fate :-)

This is the answer by one of the developers:

> Thank you for taking part* in our project ;-) Feel free to express your opinion exhaustively on our feedback site**. You can reach me by mail or phone throughout this day.
>
> Greets, Marvin

* you could also translate this as "Thank you for your condolences concerning our project", this ambiguity is likely intentional.

** They're acually using uservoice as their feedback site. As an answer to the [SO similarity question](http://codekicker.uservoice.com/pages/21227-general/suggestions/309443-was-bringt-der-stackoverflow-klon-?ref=title), the admin basically claims that they see themselves as an addition to SO for German speaking users. Quote:

> As far as site design and features go, we hope to even do some things better than our [guides / idols]. Do you like the home page?

Nothing wrong with what they're doing, but I don't get why they don't really acknowledge SO publicly.

Oh well...

Comment: Nothing *legally* wrong. But they'll be going to hell for that.

Comment: At least they would if there was something like hell. But you know what I mean.

Comment: If there's no hell, hopefully there's at least karma, and then hopefully there's "What goes around comes around".

Comment: Thanks for that uplifting comment, DanR. When I read the answers on the linked question, I'm sure you're right. codekicker seems to be full of idiots.

Answer (score 3):

It's a clone as per this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/so-clones/15654#15654). It was one of the first if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some crossover as well.  See these two questions:

SO: [What means the error-message ‘java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded’ in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/what-means-the-error-message-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-excee)

codecicker: [Was bedeutet 'GC overhead limit exceeded' bei Java?](http://codekicker.de/fragen/Was-bedeutet-GC-overhead-limit-exceeded-bei-Java/203)

EDIT:
on further examination of the posts, I guess you would know that ;)

Comment: Yes I try out both communities. Stackoverflow worked much better in this case.

Comment: The "What means" grammar uses a more "german" ordering, so it's likely it was asked on the german site in the first place.  What would be interesting is if one of these clone sites tried to automatically translate and post new questions to SO on behalf of their users, and then clone answers back.  That could get tiresome (though easy enough to block, I suppose).

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: The edit and the first comment explain it all: It's the same asker. Also the same as the OP on this very question.

Comment: Yes. And I'm not sure, that I posted it first at codekicker. German grammar I use all the time in my english - as I'm a native german speaker. Sorry for my bad english.