# StackOverflow clones, legal?

Tags: discussion, copyright, clone

I ran across [this website](http://hwanswers.com/) and it really bothers me how similar it is to SO in EVERY aspect without giving any credit whatsoever and even copyrighting the website for themselves. Is this legal?

Comment: It bothers me more that people are so willing to write off their education so cheaply.

Comment: @beska The majority of those questions are straight from WebAssign, which changes the numbers and subsequently the answer of every homework problem. Googling part of the question comes in handy when you need a hint :P

Comment: @Downvoter: You might want to take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner

Comment: Doesn't HWAnswers.com represent something that StackOverflow is **against**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100226155312-a1b2fb6269ba)">
```

It's a stackexchange site

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the fact that this particular site is Stack Exchange one, of course clones are legal. If it's written from the ground-up, then its someone else's tool.

There have been a variety of clone projects already started, such as: [Stacked - an Open Source implementation of StackOverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16780/stacked-an-open-source-implementation-of-stackoverflow-com); [Am I allowed to make a Stack Overflow clone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5558/am-i-allowed-to-make-a-stackoverflow-clone); [Is codekicker using the software behind StackOverflow or did they program a clone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20819/is-codekicker-using-the-software-behind-stackoverflow-or-did-they-program-a-clone); [Is this Russian site a legitimate copy of the Stack Overflow package?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40455/is-this-russian-site-a-legitimate-copy-of-stackoverflow-package)

Comment: Note that there are _some_ limits. Look up "trade dress", for example, and design patents. (Granted these are abused a lot, but they're meant to provide protection for particularly distinctive designs that rise to roughly the level of a trademark.) If hwanswers _were_ a clone, it would be skirting a bit close to the edge.

Comment: And, in terms of copyright, see Substantial Similarity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantial_similarity

Comment: Not that a Russian site would be all that concerned with the specifics of US copyright, patent, and "trade dress" laws, looking at the last citation.  The US has not quite succeeded in conquering the world yet.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [Stack Exchange site](http://meta.stackexchange.com), which would be 'legal'.

Comment: Why the scare quotes? :)

Answer (score 0):

Wow you get [prizes](http://hwanswers.com/rewards) for reputation on that site!

Jon Skeet could make a killing.

Comment: Meh, Jon Skeet merely has an iPod Shuffle...